# Eclipse does not close ServerSocket completely

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, network-programming, serversocket

I have run an application contains ServerSocket and after several logins of clients and server termination the server cannot restart because it throws an `java.net.BindException` and it says `Address already in use: JVM_Bind`.

The server creation is normal (`ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port)`

The Console icon in eclipse is gray (there are not any running applications).

I checked the listenning ports in CMD and it shows my port even after eclipse terminate my application.

Only after restart Eclipse the problem is resolved...

What can make that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You seem to not close the socket http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#close()

Comment: Maybe it Eclipse bug? Reinstall will help?

Comment: "even after eclipse terminate my application." Do you hit the red button and kill the application or do you shut it down properly.

Comment: Whether I hit the red button to terminate the application it says the execption. But if I restart eclipse the port is removed from the computer ports (I have checked by netstat -a) and I can launch the application

Comment: When you just terminate the application using the red button Eclipse kills it. I bet your socket is not closed (as the code is not called). You can debug it and add a breakpoint where your close code is.

Comment: Usually I not terminate it with the red button but with windows closing event that do server.close();

Comment: So is the port still blocked when you have **verified** that your `SocketServer::close` is called?

Comment: Yes. It still blocked

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:** I got the answer after a lot of deep exploration.

The problem maker is the Windows Builder plugin of eclipse.

When I turn it to the "Deisgn" Mode  on it run the code, so it run the server creation code too, and it link the port to Eclipse.exe process.

Now the restart eclipse solution is understandable.